# Failed resolution of: Lcom/plaid/link/OpenPlaidLink

Tags: android, kotlin, plaid

I'm trying to create a library that needs to run plaid inside it.
I'm adding the plaid dependency to the library and running it as soon as the activity is instantiated.

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Create an android library and add plaid sdk as dependency
2. Create an    activity and launch plaid into onCreate method
3. Import the library in
   your android application and call the library activity

**Expected Result**
Plaid should be launched, and you'll see plaid flow

**Actual Result**
App crash
**Adding plaid sdk dependency in the android application that is importing this SDK, plaid works, but I need the library to be in charge of installing this dependency**

Error screenshot
[image]

build.gradle library
[image]